# Changing KineticJS text color on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I'm trying to change the color of a Kinetic.Text object when the user mouses over. This is what I'm doing:

```
menuTab.on('mouseover', function() {
    menuTab.fill = "white";
    layerMenu.draw();
});
menuTab.on('mouseout', function() {
    menuTab.fill = "#BB9999";
    layerMenu.draw();
});
```

But as of these last few KineticJS updates. This does not seem to work at all. I've also tried to use:

```
menuTab.setFill('...');
```

Instead, however that won't help either. 
If anyone can help me solve this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining `menuTab`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've instantiated the `menuTab` and `layerMenu` objects correctly, the following code should enable you to manipulate the `menuTab` color on hover:

```
<script src="path/to/kinetic.js"></script>
<script defer="defer">

    var menuTab = new Kinetic.Rect({...});      
    var layerMenu = new Kinetic.Layer();

    menuTab.on('mouseover', function() {
        this.setFill('white');
        layerMenu.draw();
    });

    menuTab.on('mouseout', function() {
        this.setFill('#BB9999');
        layerMenu.draw();
    });

</script>
```